# How to create text file in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem with sql server. I want to run a command in sql server for 691 times,(for each VID).

But the values of VID column are not Sequential and Ascending. so how can I run this command.

My means that I want to run this command for each VID, that the number of its value is 691, and the min value is 11, and the max value is 7668. And then I want to save results for  each VID in text file.

The command is:

```
declare @vid integer

DECLARE @FileName varchar(8000)

declare @bcpCommand varchar(8000)

set @vid = 1

while (@vid < 692)

begin

SET @FileName = 'd:\re'+ CONVERT(char(8),@vid)+'.txt'



SET @bcpCommand =  'bcp "select ak_from,ak_to,w from [socialdb].[dbo].final where ???? "  queryout "'+ @FileName + '" -C -T -c -S SONY-VAIO\SQLEXPRESS1'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand



set @vid = (@vid + 1)

end
```

I want to do this with sql server 2008. The first records is one of my table records.

I should classification records according to vid, and each record that has a same vid must be in a seprat txt file.

For saving in text file I use bcp. and I don’t have problem with that. My problem is with the Query in sql server that do this. As I said, the first records are  saved in table that its name is final.
How to write the query for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What exactly is your question? There are many ways to do this, what you have tried so far? What problem do you have?

Comment: How to write the query for this?

Comment: I don't want to appear unhelpful, but it sounds like you haven't done any research or tried to find a solution yourself. There are [dozens of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+export+text+file) on this site already about exporting data to flat files. You will usually get better answers if you show that you have tried to solve your own problem before asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing the query for this necessitates that you have the data in some queryable format (e.g. a table in your DB).  Once you have that you can easily write a query that SELECTs just the columns you are looking for (ak_from, ak_to, w) and places the result into a text file via *bcp* (see: [Using bcp utility to export SQL queries to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140947/using-bcp-utility-to-export-sql-queries-to-a-text-file) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

Presuming you'll have more than just 5 records and 3 VIDs you could write the bcp within a cursor so that you can loop and create multiple text files based on your conditions.

For the sake of example, the code below simply puts the 5 records into a temp table, and then outputs each of the three text files.

```
CREATE TABLE ##tbl
(
    Vid INT NOT NULL
    ,ak_from INT NOT NULL
    ,ak_to INT NOT NULL
    ,w INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO ##tbl
SELECT 11, 164885, 164885, 24
UNION SELECT 11, 164885, 431072, 3
UNION SELECT 51, 731754, 690695, 2
UNION SELECT 51, 204086, 316310, 2
UNION SELECT 54, 818522, 501263, 1

DECLARE @vid VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @querytextNoVid VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @querytext VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @filelocation VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE vid_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT vid FROM ##tbl
OPEN vid_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM vid_cursor INTO @vid


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @querytext = '"SELECT ak_from, ak_to, w FROM ##tbl WHERE vid = ' + @vid + '"'
    SET @filelocation = '"c:\out_vid' + @vid + '.dat"'
    SET @cmd = 'bcp ' + @querytext + ' queryout ' + @filelocation + ' -T -c'
    EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd

    FETCH NEXT FROM vid_cursor INTO @vid
END
CLOSE vid_cursor
DEALLOCATE vid_cursor

DROP TABLE ##tbl
```

You'll need to ensure xp_cmdshell is enabled via sp_configure (see: [Enable 'xp_cmdshell' SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131491/enable-xp-cmdshell-sql-server))

Comment: Adding, I had to include as Exec master..xp_cmdshell @sqlCSV, no_output. the no_output was necessary because I was running in a third party software and just want to "ignore" the possible messages.