# Need to get the output from azure sqldatabase

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

PowerShell to redirect the below command output to a text file:

```
$tables = invoke-sqlcmd –ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName -Username $Username -Password $Password  -InputFile $filename.fullname  | Out-String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbName="DatabaseName"

$instanceName="ServerInstanceName"

$filePath="OutputFilePath"

$query = "SELECT name FROM sys.Tables"

$tableNames = Invoke-SqlCmd –ServerInstance $instanceName -Database $dbName –Query $query

New-Item -Path $filePath -ItemType directory

foreach($TName in $tableNames)

{

$fileileName=$filePath + "\\" + $TName.get_Item(0).ToString() + ".txt"

$getTableData="select * from " + $TName.get_Item(0).ToString()

Invoke-SqlCmd –ServerInstance $instanceName -Database $dbName –Query $getTableData | Export-Csv -Path $fileName -NoTypeInformation

}
```

[image: Fig. Export DB Table data into a text file]

Please Refer: [Click here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660616/export-all-sql-server-tables-at-once-to-txt-or-csv)

Comment: Actually I need to execute One or more sql files from a folder . Need to get the Output like Each statement it needs to pick from sql file and get the output whether the statement is inserted or updated or alter database etc..  I need to read each statement in a sql file and print the output accordingly.

Comment: For all the statement I need to look in each sql file and print the values according to the statement  to the console Output.SELECT - extracts data from a database
 UPDATE - updates data in a database
 DELETE - deletes data from a database
 INSERT INTO - inserts new data into a database
 CREATE DATABASE - creates a new database
 ALTER DATABASE - modifies a database
 CREATE TABLE - creates a new table
 ALTER TABLE - modifies a table
 DROP TABLE - deletes a table
 CREATE INDEX - creates an index (search key)
 DROP INDEX - deletes an index                          Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please update the original question or post a new question with updated requirement.  If my answer has helped you kindly upvote and accept it as a answer to help the other community members. Thanks

Comment: Hi Delliganesh , .Actually I need to execute One or more sql files from a folder using powershell . Need to get the Output like Each statement it needs to pick from sql file and get the output whether the statement is inserted or updated or alter database etc.. I need to read each statement in a sql file and print the output accordingly.

Comment: Hi raja sekhar reddy, I understood but your question is different to the original requirement. Kindly modify your question or post a new question. Thank you.